# Impressão de Lista Simplesmente encadeada/Tipo Abstrato de Dados - TAD

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

estou com dificuldade não implementação da função void exibe_lst(Telem* lst), não consigo fazer com que os elementos inseridos sejam exibidos devido uma conversão que não sei como resolver.

Segue o link do TAD.

[Lista](https://github.com/mit3719/TAD)

Comment: "não consigo fazer com que os elementos inseridos sejam exibidos devido uma conversão" - como assim ? Quais os elementos  e qual a conversão ? Tem como detalhar o que está a acontecer exatamente e o que não está a funcionar como pretende e porque ? Assim como os possíveis erros que são mostrados ? Aproveite e coloque na pergunta apenas o código relevante ao problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void exibe_lst(Telem* lst){
  Telem* i;

  for(i = lst ;i != NULL ;i = i->info )
  {
    printf("informacao: %d\n", i->info);
  }
}
```

no `i =  i->info, não seria i = i->next?`

Comment: sim. tenho que imprimir as informações e não um ponteiro ... no printf ta certo e no for, esta errado. o certo é assim mesmo @NetinhoSantos. Mas o problema era nos protótipos, no arquivos main.c, que tinha a função exibe_lst ... com void no inicio e a passagem de parâmetro tava errada também. Agora ta funcionando que é um beleza.